# Postgresql doesn't working with Citus and pg_stat_statements at the same time

Tags: postgresql, citus, postgresql-extensions

So, I built the PostgreSQL with citus extension in docker.
I use the official documentation in citus, then I run this command in the terminal.

```
docker run -d --network citus-network --name citus_coordinator -p 5500:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword citusdata/citus:11.1
```

Then Database successfully building.
But I want to create the `pg_stat_statements` extension.
I configuration the  `postgresql.conf` file.

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
track_activity_query_size = 2048
```

Then I restarted the PostgreSQL container. Wrote the this query

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements;
```

in terminal.
I saw this error

```
[55000] ERROR: pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
```

I didn't understand, why the config file didn't see this extension, What was my mistake?

Comment: Did you check the result from SHOW shared_preload_libraries;

Comment: @FrankHeikens   Yeah, I check it, and i see just Citus

Comment: How code you see Citus in the shared_preload_libraries when it's not there in your configuration? At least not in the example you showed us. Are you sure you're on the same database server?

Comment: @FrankHeikens  I run the postgresql container with a citus image. That's why the citus extension is by default coming in postgresql.

Comment: How did you edit the config file?  Probably either the changes never got applied, or they were overwritten by citus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
I am running the PostgreSQL container with `postgres:latest` image. Then I entered the container. So, I installed the citus from [here](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/installation/single_node_debian.html) into the container. Then installed `apt-get install postgresql-contrib` into the container.Next step, run `create extension pg_stat_statements;` And everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If using citus, citus should always be your first shared preload library. So your postgres.conf should look like:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'citus,pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
track_activity_query_size = 2048
```

If you have workers, you need to change their postgresql.conf as well.

Then you need to restart the databases (coordinator and workers) which you can achieve by:

```
docker restart <container_name>
```

You can confirm this worked with:

```
SHOW shared_preload_libraries;
```